# How to use list comprehensions for for-loop with additional operations

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to simplify this construction with list comprehensions:

```
words = {}
counter = 0

for sentence in text:
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in words:
            words[word] = counter
            counter += 1
```

If there was something like post-increment, it could be written like:

```
words = {word: counter++ for sentence in text for word in sentence if word not in words}
```

How should I do it in pythonic way?

For example:

```
text =
[
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
['bbb', 'ddd'],
['aaa', 'ccc', 'eee']
]
```

Desired result:

```
words = {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 3, 'ddd': 4, 'eee': 5}
```

Order does not matter.

## UPD:

I found an interesting solution:

```
words = {}
counter = (x for x in range(10**6))

[words.update({word: counter.next()}) for sentence in text for word in sentence if word not in words]
```

`update` method allows to check if word in dictionary already.
Maybe I should use `len(words)` instead of `counter.next()`, but I thought that counter will be faster (O(1) vs. O(dict_size)).

Comment: Are you trying to find count of unique words? I would suggest to look at `collections.Counter` object.

Comment: can you please add the desire input & output ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, you are right. Also I want to enumerate them. In order of appearance, for example.

Comment: @Usman, examples were added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a dictionary, then you should use its `setdefault` method, it makes this kind of tasks trivial.

```
words = {}
for sentence in text:
    for word in sentence:
        words[word] = words.setdefault(word, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I think the question needs an answer that uses list comprehension.

Comment: I know, but he's asking for a pythonic way, a list comprehension is pythonic but not always a good solution

Comment: `dict` with lots of `setdefault` to 0 smells like `collections.defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that with both ways, but mine uses a built-in type without needing any import, that's why I prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. This one is without using any external modules, one liner:

```
s = "a a a b b a a b a b a b"
d = [[(out, out.update([(v, out.get(v, 0) + 1)])) for v in s.split()] for out in [{}]][0][0][0]
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 7, 'b': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise variables inside a list/dictionary comprehension. But you could always do it in two steps using a list then a dictionary comprehension :

```
# We list the different words in the text
list_words = [word for word in sentence for sentence in text]

# Using numpy's unique function and the count() 
# function we use a dictionary comprehension
dict_words = {word : list_words.count(word) for word in np.unique(list_words)}
```

Comment: Maybe rather use `set` instead of involving numpy. And you could integrate the creation of `list_words` into the list comprehension, too.

Comment: If I use a set then I can't count the number of words which is the goal of OP

Comment: How would you add list_words in the dictionnary comprehension since I use it in my for loop in the dictionnary ?

Comment: I meant instead of `np.unique`, which is just to remove the duplicates I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use list comprehension, this one works:

```
def countWords(content):
    allWords = [word for words in content for word in words]
    return {word: allWords.count(word) for word in set(allWords)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was kinda fun to play with.  You really can't do it in one line (and that's ok, 1 line solutions aren't always the best), but you can do it with all comprehensions.

```
d={}
s = "a a a b b a a b a b a b"
x = [(word, 1) for word in s.split()]
d = {word: sum(cnt for w,cnt in x if w == word) for word,_ in x if not word in d.keys()}
```

`d` is the destination dictionary that will hold the word counts. `s` is one of the sentences (you can expand this to extract at more than one level if you have a list of sentences).  `x` is an intermediate list that holds a pair for each word that is `('word', 1)`, and then we use that to sum across the pairs to get the final count.

At the end, the value of `x` and `d` is:

```
>>> x
[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)]
>>> d
{'a': 7, 'b': 5}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the `count()` functrion.  @vlemaistre 's solution is better, but I'll leave this here for another idea, and some more depth on comprehensions.